# Setting the ResultSet of native query JPA to POJO throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, type-conversion

I want to convert the resultset List<Object[]> to entity class.
My Native query:

```
 @Query("select type,name,latitude,longitute,111.045* DEGREES (ACOS(COS(RADIANS(:latitude))*COS (RADIANS(latitude))*COS(RADIANS(:longitute) - RADIANS (longitute))"
            + "+SIN (RADIANS (:latitude))*SIN (RADIANS(latitude)))) As distance_in_km from Place ORDER BY distance_in_km ")
     List<Object[]> findBylattitudeAndlongitute(@Param("latitude") double latitude ,@Param("longitute") double longitute );
```

My entity class:

```
@EnableCaching
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLACEDETAILS_H")
public class Place {

    public Place() {
    }   
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String Code;
    private String Name;
    private String Code1;   
    private String Name2;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitute;

}
```

service class:

```
 List<Object[]>  places = Repository.findBylattitudeAndlongitute(latitude, longitute);  
Place place = null;
for (Object[] pla : places) {
    place.setType((String) pla[0]);
    place.setName((String) pla[1]); 
}
```

Since the distance_in_km in not a variable in place entity, I am unable to map the resultset directly. The query executed successfully and Im getting response List<Object[]>.

I tried setting the pla[0] to type but It shows null pointer exception.
help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add the following `transient` column:

   ```
    @Transient
    private Double distance_in_km;
   ```
2. You need to change your Spring Data @Query to a Hibernate native query instead:

   ```
    List<Place> places = (List<Place>) session.createSQLQuery("""
        select 
            type as {p.type}, 
            name as {p.name}, 
            latitude as {p.latitude}, 
            longitute as {p.longitute},
            111.045* DEGREES (
                ACOS(
                    COS(RADIANS(:latitude)) * 
                    COS (RADIANS(latitude)) *
                    COS(RADIANS(:longitute) - RADIANS (longitute)) +
                    SIN (RADIANS (:latitude))*SIN (RADIANS(latitude)))
            ) As {p.distanceInKm} 
        from Place p 
        ORDER BY {p.distanceInKm}
        """
    )
    .setParameter("latitude", latitude)
    .setParameter("longitute", longitute)
    .addEntity("p", Place.class)
    .list();
   ```